# Split a string by no delimiter, then index into object using alpha indexing

Tags: jquery, object, split

I want to split a string by no delimiter (effectively splitting it by each character), then index into an object in alphabetical order. I want it to utilize jQuery.

Here is my attempt, but this splits into an array, and elements are accessed by square brackets (`obj_to_chars[0]`, `obj_to_chars[1]`, etc), but I want to be able to access elements by using the dot notation, like so: `obj_of_chars.a`, `obj_of_chars.b`, etc.

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
var obj_of_chars = {};
obj_of_chars = str.split("");
console.log(obj_of_chars);
// what I have: [ "T", "h", "e", " ", "q", "u", "i", "c", "k", " ", "b", "r", "o", "w", "n", " fox", " ", "j", "u", "m", "p", "s", " ", "o", "v", "e", "r", " ", "t", "h", "e", " ", "l", "a", "z", "y", " ", "d", "o", "g", "." ]
// what I want: { a: "T", b: "h", c: "e", d: " ", e: "q", ..., aa, ab, ... }
```

EDIT: **The solution should allow more than 26 characters in the object.** (sorry to those who already wrote a piece of code, just realized I needed more than 26 characters)

Comment: You shouldn't change the rules of the game after you have asked the question. Especially when you say `should allow more than 26 characters`, but specify in no way how that is supposed to be accomplished. Should they switch to `aa`, `bb`, etc?

Comment: Yes. `a`,`b`,...,`z`,`aa`,`ab`,..,`az`,`ba`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var input = "Hello world";
var output = {};
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    var prop = String.fromCharCode(97 + i); // 97 = ASCII code for "a"
    output[prop] = input.charAt(i);
}
```

If the length of the input string is more than 26, this code will spill over the alphabet and start using non-alpha characters as keys. Modify the expression that sets `prop` accordingly if you want to avoid this.

**Update:** Here's how to continue the alphanumeric property name scheme indefinitely:

```
var input = "Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world";
var output = {};
var name = ['a'];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    output[name.join("")] = input.substr(i, 1);
    for (var j = name.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if(name[j] != 'z') {
            name[j] = String.fromCharCode(name[j].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
            break;
        }
        else {
            name[j] = 'a';
            if(j == 0) {
                name.unshift('a');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that is so cool. I knew someone was going to come along and kill this with something awesomely simple.

Comment: +1. This is better than my answer (which kept the question's `.split()` idea), though you may like to use `.charAt(i)` rather than `.substr(i,1)`.

Comment: This is not well developed if it is only limited to 26 characters.

Comment: @zzatkin: What are we supposed to do after the 26th character? Read your mind? The solutions will work for *any* number of characters. If they don't work the way you want, well that's because *you have not told us* how they should work.

Comment: @Jon: Of course. :) Sorry, I left out that detail in my question. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to use jQuery, but I don't understand why.

This can be done easily with plain JavaScript, so other than using a jQuery `.each()` method I'm not sure how jQuery would help you.

```
var str = 'my string',
    obj_of_chars = {},
    arr_of_chars = str.split("");

for (var i = 0; i < arr_of_chars.length; i++)
    obj_of_chars[String.fromCharCode(i+97)] = arr_of_chars[i];

console.log(obj_of_chars);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bGSvD/